# Text searching with line Number Complication

Tags: java, regex, string, full-text-search, text-files

EDIT:
Thanks dawww, the problem was with the Encoding, i changed it to UFT-8, and now the program works perfectly well. Just a tad slow.

I am in desperate need of help.

THE PROBLEM:

I have a TreeSet with words i took out of a text, they're all lower case and follow this regex("[^a-zA-Z]"), what i need is to compare word by word of the TreeSet with the text i took them from and get the line number each word appear, store them into and ArrayList and return.

I have the following Code:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> search(String word, String book) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    FileReader path = new FileReader(book);
    LineNumberReader read = new LineNumberReader(path);
    ArrayList<Integer> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;

    for(line = read.readLine(); line != null; line = read.readLine()){
        if(line.toLowerCase().contains(word)){
            lines.add(read.getLineNumber());
        }
    }
    return lines;
}
```

The idea is to use the search method's return as a value into a Map> (each word and the lines)

like this:

```
for(String s : words){
        map.put(s, search(s , book));
    }
```

words is the TreeSet with the strings i took from the text (Alice in wonderland by Lewis Carroll).

the code doesn't work, and i don't know why. The code compiles and runs but the map is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To check if `line` contains `word` case insensitive, you can use Apache Commons Lang library, and specifically [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#containsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method: `StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(CharSequence str, CharSequence searchStr)`.
  This library has also other utility methods that can help, for example `strip` and `trim` are useful for cleaning Strings before operate with them.
- Another problem can be with the encoding of the file. `FileReader` always use the platform default encoding. Try to use `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), <encoding>)` to read from the file.

Comment: Encoding problem as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `contains` method is case sensative.

And you are making line to lower case `line.toLowerCase()`

It may not be matching because of that.

Please put System.out.print statement for line.toLowerCase() and word to check it

```
System.out.print(line.toLowerCase()+" "+word);
```

And if that is the case, solution will be to lower case the word also in if condition.

```
if(line.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())){
        lines.add(read.getLineNumber());
}
```

Comment: All the words on the TreeSet are lower case (the parameter word is already lower cased).